# Можно ли в WinSCP использовать подсистему Linux вместо PuTTY?

Tags: putty, wsl, winscp

Чтобы передавать туда логин и пароль и подключаться автоматически по SSH к серверу, на который зашёл по FTP. WinSCP портабельная.

1. В официальной документации говорится про несуществующий каталог Sysnative. https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#openssh
2. Но если указать существующий путь C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe, WinSCP ругается что файл не найден.
3. И правда, если вручную искать этот файл, его не будет видно в проводнике. http://prntscr.com/jmsp9g
4. Если в документации это описано, значит теоретически возможно и должно подключаться по дефолту. В каком месте я ошибаюсь?

Comment: По ссылке что вы дали сказано, дословно "_Если вы хотите использовать OpenSSH ssh клиент в среде 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' ..._". Но вы явно не используете ssh в этой среде, потому что ее надо отдельно устанавливать на windows (все сказано по ссылке из этой фразы)

Comment: И вообще там весь пункт озаглавлен "_Using OpenSSH Instead of PuTTY_" т.е. "Использование OpenSSH _вместо_ PuTTY". Но WinSCP никакого отношения к OpenSSH не имеет и значит этот пункт вообще нет смысла читать, если вы работаете с WinSCP

Comment: То есть кроме дебильных путти нельзя ничего с винсцп интегрировать? Печально.

Comment: Почему дебильных ? puTTY отличный клиент. просто идеология SSH не подразумевает автоматической передачи паролей, потому что это не безопасно. Для входа без ввода паролей существуют ключи. puTTY позволяет их использовать, так же как и передавать имя пользователя. например https://habr.com/post/127521/ И WinSCP то же позволяет использовать ключи https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key

Comment: Может и отличный клиент но зачем, когда есть нормальная линуксовая консоль. Не хотелось бы плодить терминалы. Безопасность это хорошо, но у пользователя тоже должен быть выбор. Вот я из дома делаю сайты на богом забытом хостинге, там у меня типа песочница, зачем мне постоянно вводить пароль или гуглить как использовать ключи. Это уже к ссшникам риторический вопрос.

Comment: постоянно вводить пароль для безопасности того места, куда вы заходите. не особо за это переживаете - сделайте пароль из 1 символа. а имя пользователя putty и сам без всяких ключе сам введет

Comment: И заметьте SSH переводиться как secure shell, так что его разработчики просто обязаны были думать о безопасности. А безопасность и "взять и просто войти" это противоположные вещи. Зачем выбирать ssh, если нужно "просто", используйте telnet и ftp

Comment: И кстати, с ключами дико удобно, никаким средствам windows такое и не снилось. Вы делаете один единственный ключ и прописываете его на всех системах, куда вам надо заходить. Т.е. время вы тратите 1 раз, а при начале работы с любой новой niх системой вам достаточно закинуть на нее 1 файл и все. Главное что бы файл ключа у вас не стащили с вашей рабочей машины :)

Comment: Ладно, убедили, буду разбираться с ключами. =)